# disable/disregard a second parameter based on the first parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have 2 multi-value parameters in my report. When we generate the report using only one of them a problem arises. If I select a value for parameter 1 and keep parameter 2 unselected I get an error:

> Please select a value for the parameter Param2

This happens even if I check "allow blank value" in the parameter's properties.

In addition: is there a way to make a set a parameter to be enabled/disabled based on a another parameter's value? For example:

- if I create another parameter having values Param1, Param2;
- if I select a value for Param1 the report will be generated based only on values selected in Param1, disabling or disregarding Param2

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

My workaround for this scenario is to fiddle with the Dataset driving the Available Values list for Param2.  You need to set it up so that when the particular Param1 value is selected, the only row that will match will be a dummy row (e.g. 'N/A'). This might involve a UNION ALL to generate that dummy row.

I use the same dataset for Default Values so that the dummy row will be automatically selected when the Param1 value is selected.

You then need to cater to that dummy Param2 value in the other datasets that refer to Param2, e.g. SELECT ... WHERE ( @Param2 = 'N/A' OR Column2 = @Param2 ).